# According to the image that I present here, how can I do this process in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

[Diseño aplicacion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbwUw.jpg)

I'm working on a Bluetooth application to control a timer remotely, but I haven't been able to achieve what is presented in the image yet, any idea of how I can solve this, please?

By the way, this is done through a tabbed layout.

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: Please upload a more clear image, are you trying to create an android studio application to control a timer remotely?